# Ошибка в цикле,при переносе данных с матрицы во временную матрицу

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, динамические-массивы

Стоит задача:

> Добавить К строк в конец матрицы

Вот код:

```
cout << "Enter K:";
cin >> k;
  
int** tmpmatrix = new int*[string + k];
for (i = 0; i < string; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
        matrix[i] = new int[column];
        
for (i = 0; i < string; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
    { 
        tmpmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];  
    }
}

for (i = string; i < string + k; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
    { 
        tmpmatrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10));  
    }
}
```

Ошибка происходит в цикле. В чем может проблема?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @EOF Запись значений во временную матрицу с матрицы

Comment: @ EOF ,точно ошибся ,Спасибо огромное за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас проблема в первом цикле. Скорее всего он должен иметь такой вид:

```
int** tmpmatrix = new int*[string + k];
for (i = 0; i < string + k; i++)
    tmpmatrix[i] = new int[column];
```

Comment: Да,все верно.Благодарю за помощь )